# Three lines to find the greatest product in a string of numbers in Python

Tags: python

Full disclosure: this is for an assignment. Simply getting working code is enough, but doing this in three lines gets me extra credit.

I'm trying to take a 1000-digit string and find the largest product of 5 consecutive digits. You may recognize this as Project Euler's Problem #8.

I've tried a lot of options, but I seem to be stuck. I'm working on figuring out if I can make a `lambda` statement that will work, but I have no experience with `lambda` so it's evading me.

Here's what I have so far:

```
for i in range(1, 996):
    max = int(number[i+0]) * int(number[i+1]) * int(number[i+2]) * int(number[i+3]) * int(number[i+4]) if max < int(number[i+0]) * int(number[i+1]) * int(number[i+2]) * int(number[i+3]) * int(number[i+4]) else max = max
return max
```

That doesn't work and triggers `SyntaxError: can't assign to conditional expression`.

I don't want outright code, or at least not a complete function, but just a little help understanding how I can move forward.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're asking... I'm not asking anyone to get me extra credit, only to steer me in the right direction. I've been reading the Python API for hours and am no closer to a resolution now than I was this morning.

Comment: He's saying you should accept some answers on some of your previous questions.

Comment: Friggin python... in virtually any other language the 3 lines requirement would be meaningless.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart: Think of it as a 3 semicolon rule in your favorite language.

Comment: @Volatility Oh! I'm sorry, I'm still learning all the features around here.. I wasn't aware of the option to choose a correct answer! I've fixed that mistake though. I'm really sorry!

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart You can combine lines with semicolons in Python too (although you shouldn't in normal code).

Comment: @recursive Common Lisp. What now?

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart: You are beyond such childish concerns as line count.  You are enlightened. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't legal python:

```
x = y if z else x = w
```

This is:

```
x = y if z else w
```

So is this:

```
if z: x = y
```

By the way, there is a one line solution, that is much shorter and clearer than your three.

Comment: A one line solution? Interesting! For now, though, I'm still having trouble with this conditional expression. So if I said `if (max < ...): max = ...` would that be syntactically correct?

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I've made the changes necessary, but I have to define `max` on a separate line before I can use it in the conditional expression. Is there a better way to do that, one that doesn't use an extra line?

Answer (score 1):

`=` appears twice in your (very long) line.  Effectively you have this:

```
max = something if something else max = max
```

which Python parses as:

```
max = (something if something else max) = max
```

And, indeed, you can't assign to a conditional expression, which is that whole thing in the middle.

You probably didn't intend to have the final `= max` at the end.

Comment: Thank you! I'm getting a better understanding of this now. So the additional clause doesn't allow for a different potential "="... I'll keep that in mind :)

Comment: you're assigning to `max` either way, so it doesn't really matter  :)  (and btw that's a bad name for a variable; python has a builtin function named `max`)

Answer (score 1):

Look into:

- **the built-in max function** to find the greatest number in a sequence,
- **the built-in map function** to apply a function to all elements in a list,
- **the built-in reduce function** to obtain a single object as a result of applying a function that returns a single object repeatedly to two elements in a list,
- **lambda definitions** to be able to define function objects that you can pass to map() and reduce(),
- and **list comprehensions** (and generators, which are very similar) to compose the above functions in a one-liner.

Comment: I feel guilty for accepting an upvote for my original answer, so I elaborated on it.

Comment: No need to feel guilty! It was great before, and excellent now!

Answer (score 1):

```
In [15]: def myinput(l,n):
    ...:     for x in l:
    ...:         yield l[x:x+n]
    ...:         

In [16]: max([reduce(lambda a,b:a*b, x) for x in myinput(range(1000),5) if len(x)==5])
Out[16]: 985084775273880L
```

Answer (score 1):

Like recursive mentioned, there is a simple one-liner solution. It involves using the `max` function - always bad to name variables after builtins!

In Python 2 it looks something like this:

```
max(reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, map(int, num[i:i+5])) for i in xrange(996))
```

In Python 3 `reduce` was removed, so you have to get it through `functools`:

```
from functools import reduce
max(reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, map(int, num[i:i+5])) for i in range(996))
```